# Как вы инициализируете view элементы?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

В работе начал сталкиваться с тем, что на экране очень много разные вьюшек, сложная разметка и т.д. Что-то нужно показывать, что-то прятать и всегда помнить, какая переменная за что отвечает, чтобы по несколько раз не инициализировать. (Использую библиотеку `AQuery` вместо `findViewById()`.) В итоге у меня выходит вот такой код.
Правильно так делать? Как вы выходите из таких ситуаций?

```
 private void initAllViews() {
        emptyList = aq.id(R.id.tv_no_operations_text).getTextView();
        statementText = aq.id(R.id.tv_statment_text).getTextView();
        statementText.setTypeface(typeface);
        btnGetStatement = aq.id(R.id.bt_get_card_receipt).getButton();
        btnGetStatement.setTypeface(typeface);
        historyPeriod = aq.id(R.id.bankproductHistoryPeriod).getTextView();
        bankProductHistoryWeekly = aq.id(R.id.bankproductHistoryWeekly).getTextView();
        bankProductHistoryMonth = aq.id(R.id.bankproductHistoryMonth).getTextView();
        dateFrom = aq.id(R.id.bankproductDetailsDateFrom).getTextView();
        dateTill = aq.id(R.id.bankproductDetailsDateTill).getTextView();
        loadingCard = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.ll_loading_card).getView();
        datePicker = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.bankproductDetailsWeekPickerFrame).getView();
        transferToLayout = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.ll_action_on_card).getView();
        transferFromLayout = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.ll_action_from_card).getView();
        blockLayout = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.ll_action_block_card).getView();
        payFromLayout = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.ll_action_pay_from_card).getView();
        infoFrame = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.bankproduct_details_infoFrame).getView();
        llRequisites = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.ll_requisites).getView();
        actionsFrame = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.bankproduct_details_actionsFrame).getView();
        cardBlocked = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.bank_product_details_card_blocked).getView();
        creditInformation = (LinearLayout) aq.id(R.id.ll_credit_information).getView();
        bankProductInfo = (FrameLayout) aq.id(R.id.bankproduct_info_button_acc).getView();
        bankProductActions = (FrameLayout) aq.id(R.id.bankproduct_actions_button).getView();
        monthPickerFrame = (FrameLayout) aq.id(R.id.bankproductDetailsMonthPickerFrame).getView();
        frameCards = (FrameLayout) aq.id(R.id.frame_cards).getView();
        frameRefreshCards = (FrameLayout) aq.id(R.id.frame_refresh_cards).getView();
        frameProductDetails = (FrameLayout) aq.id(R.id.frame_product_details).getView();
        actionsText = aq.id(R.id.bankproduct_actions_text_acc).getTextView();
        infoText = aq.id(R.id.bankproduct_info_text_acc).getTextView();
        actionsSelected = aq.id(R.id.bankproduct_actions_selected).getView();
        infoSelected = aq.id(R.id.bankproduct_info_selected_acc).getView();
        progressBar = aq.id(R.id.progress_cards_receipt).getProgressBar();
        progressBarCards = aq.id(R.id.progress_cards).getProgressBar();
        refreshCardStatement = aq.id(R.id.iv_refresh_card_receipt).getImageView();
        errorText = aq.id(R.id.tv_error_text).getTextView();
    }
```

Comment: Лучше вместо этого заюзать roboguce, имхо код будет гораздо читабельней.
И мне кажется, у вас что-то не так в проектировании пошло.

Comment: одна фигня, в Roboguce это просто на уровне аннотаций будет

Comment: у вас слишком много View в одной сущьности (Фрагмент? Активити?). Разбейте его на несколько логических частей, и вы удивитесь, насколько прекрасна жизнь!

Comment: это фрагмент, отображается на весь экран. По сути, верхняя часть это pager, нижняя часть разделена на 2 вкладки, с кучей интерфейса, индикаторов загрузки и тд. Разбить на несколько логических частей, имеете ввиду разбить фрагмент на 3 фрагмента, например?

Comment: а чем плох этот вариант?

Comment: Непонятно и нечитаемо, но тут мне важно понять принцип. А не просто использовать аннотации или библиотеки

Comment: Много фрэймов, это наверное замена диалоговых окон?

Comment: @Garf1eld, я имел ввиду не вариант из вопроса, а вариант с выносом в разные фрагменты.

Comment: @Deadkenny, да несколько вложенных вкладок, индикаторы загрузки, emptyView, и тп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую AndroidAnnotations, примерно так:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.conversation_layout)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.conversation_menu)
public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

   @ViewById
   ListView conversationList;

   @ViewById
   EditText editMessage;

   @ViewById
   ImageButton sendMessage;

   @ViewById
   InviteConversationButton inviteConversationButton;

   @ViewById
   View buttonsLayout;

   @Pref
   MySettings settings;

   @App
   Me me;
   //ну и т.д.
}
```

Возникающие кастомные переменные показывающие различные состояния вьюшек и проч. UI элементы пихаю в кастомные `ViewHolder` типа:

```
public final class MessageViewHolder {
   //selector
   public boolean isThreadView;
   //fields
   public String messageId;
   public String conversationId;
   public String recipientIds;
   public ArrayList<String> addresses;
   //views
   public TextView respondent;
   public TextView body;
   public TextView date;
   public ImageView icon;
   public TextView unreadMessages;

   public MessageViewHolder() {
       addresses=new ArrayList<>();
       isThreadView=true;
   }
}
```

Далее по ходу пьесы пихаю их в именованные теги вьюшек:

```
view.setTag(R.layout.my_layout, messageViewHolder);
```

Очень удобно. Когда необходимо вытаскиваю из вьюшки и делаю то что нужно:

```
MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder=(MessageViewHolder)view.getTag(R.layout.my_layout);
if(messageViewHolder.isThreadView) {
     //blah-blah
}
```

Comment: ого в ведре появился автовайринг ))

Comment: @argamidon стесняюсь спросить: чего вы там сказали? ))

Answer (score 0):

Если обязательно нужен такой сложный view, я б попробовал группировать их в custom view.

```
public class MyCustomCompoundView extends RelativeLayout {

    TextView  emptyList;

    TextView statementText ;

    public MyCustomCompoundView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        onCreateView();
    }

    public void method() {
        //какой то код
    }

    private void onCreateView() {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, this);
        emptyList = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_operations_text);
        statementText = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_statment_text);
    }
}
```

Посмотрите [butter-knife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), оч. удобный.